# Change Stroke Color of Marker Icon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using for a Google Maps Marker (V3) the icon in the following way:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    id: "theId",
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        strokeColor: "green"
    },
    map: map,
    title: "theTitle",
    position: someLatitudeLongitude
});
```

Now after creating this marker I like to change the color run-time with a color panel.
Now this works perfectly for a polyline or polygon, but for the marker not quite well: it is changed but not real-time updated.

Code:

```
selectedShape.icon.strokeColor = color;
```

PROBLEM: Does not show color change on map. Only after saving and reloading the map, the correct color is shown.

For a polygon I use:

```
selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
```

This works fine.

So is there a set like operator for the marker or a partial refresh?

Thanks for any help.

Best regards,

Evert Wiesenekker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would bind on an event where the color changes, then call `marker.setIcon(icon_options)` on the marker to pass in the new values.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need to do is 'refresh' the marker like this:

```
marker.getIcon().strokeColor = 'green';
marker.setMap(map);
```

Or you could do:

```
marker.setIcon({
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW, 
    strokeColor:'green'
});
```